# multiple internal rewrites not working as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm having some .htaccess troubles.

I would like to take the following url:
 /index2/ **internally rewritten to** /index2.html

In my .htaccess file I have:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.html [L]
```

But the URL evanjerkunica/index2/ says:
  The requested URL /redirect:/index2.html.html.html was not found on this server.

Any idea why this keeps getting rewritten internally? Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the html exists before you apply the rule. You can do this with a condition:

```
RewriteEngine On

# extract the pathname into a capture group
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$

# test to see if the pathname + .html exists as a file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.html -f

# if both conditions are true, apply the rule:
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank you @Jon Lin - that works almost perfectly. That gives me:

Comment: The requested URL **/index.html/** was not found on this server. I also tried turning off directoryslash but that didn't help...any suggestions?